# Linear Algebra vs Nonlinear Algebra Question

Tags: linear-algebra

An unknown number is multiplied by 4 and then has five subtracted from it. It is now equal to the square root of the original unknown number squared.

> a. Is this a linear algebra problem? Justify your answer.
>
> b. How many solutions are possible? Explain why.
>
> c. Find all possible values for
> the number

I really don't want to post this question here because I know people won't like me posting these kinds of questions but this is really important to me.
My answer for (a) was yes because no part of the simplified equation has a nonlinear operation.
My answer for (b) was 1 because linear equations can only have one answer.
My answer for (c) was $\frac{5}{3}$ because

> $4x - 5 = x$
>
> $4x - 5 - x = 0$
>
> $4x - x = 5$
>
> $3x = 5$
>
> $x = \frac{5}{3}$

The textbook answers say that the answer for (a) is no. (b) is $2$ because there is a positive and negative solution and (c) is $\frac{5}{3}$. Am I doing something stupid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation for $x$ reads:

$4x-5= \sqrt{x^2}.$

Since you have $x^2$ in this equation, it is not a linear algebra problem, observe that $\sqrt{x^2} = |x| $, hence you have the equation $4x-5=|x|.$

Now we have two cases: 1. $x \ge 0$ and 2. $x<0.$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

It is normally not a linear algebra problem because of the $|x|$ term mentioned by Fred.

But you can easily turn it into a linear algebra problem by various methods.

It is just a question of how big a vector space you are willing to consider.